# Fourier expression for infinite recurring binary sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

We have infinite binary sequences of type
$$\langle g_n \rangle_{j=4}=\{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,...\} \,;\, n\to\infty$$
where $j$ indicates the length of a period.

we try to express them with a Fourier in a shape similar the spectrum:

$$G(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\,e^{(i\,2\pi\,k\,x / j)}$$

None of us is good in Fourier at all. May someone help us with the right expression.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you know about Fourier inversion? Doesn't that give you a formula for the Fourier coefficients?

Comment: Alternatively, think about $(1/4)(1^n+i^n+(-1)^n+(-i)^n)$

Comment: Gerry, thanks, this may really help us. do you have an idea for us how we could parametrize your suggestion for different j. Is there a general rule? Many many thanks. Great suggestion :-))

Comment: Fourier inversion. Fourier inversion. Fourier inversion. Or $g_n=(1/j)\sum_ke^{2\pi ikn/j}$.

Comment: thanks. got also link to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inverse Fourier in its most elegant form is for such sequences:

$$G(x)=\sum_{k=-j}^j \frac{2 \pi}{j}\,e^{(i\,2\pi\,(k-1)\,x / j)}$$

while $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and angular frequency:

$$\omega_j=\frac{2 \pi}{j}$$